# How do i get the id to be added and removed from the particular button clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").on('click', function(argument) {  
         $("button").attr('id', 'addtocart');
            var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
                if (product_id!="") {
                        $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url : "manage-cart.php",
                            data : 'product_id='+product_id,
                            success : function (response) {
                                // action to be performed if                                             successful
                                $('#addtocart').removeAttr('id');
                            }
                    })

                    }
                    
                })
            });
        </script>
```

```html
    <div class="buttons">
     <button class="" type="submit" >
       <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</button>
 </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="product_id" value ="5">
<div class="buttons">
     <button class="" type="submit" >
       <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</button>
 </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="product_id" value ="6">
<div class="buttons">
     <button class="" type="submit" >
       <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</button>
 </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="product_id" value ="7">
<div class="buttons">
     <button type="submit" >
       <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</button>
 </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="product_id" value ="8">
```

this is the script and HTML code I'm working with. When the button is clicked the id is added to all the buttons and that's not the idea I want the id to be added to just the clicked button and removed after execution of the ajax script.

Comment: try add id:  $(this).attr('id', 'addtocart') or $(argument.target).attr('id', 'addtocart')

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `$(this)`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").on('click', function(argument) {  
      var _t = $(this);
     _t.attr('id', 'addtocart');
        var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
            if (product_id!="") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "manage-cart.php",
                        data : 'product_id='+product_id,
                        success : function (response) {
                            // action to be performed if                                             successful
                            _t.removeAttr('id');
                        }
                })

                }

            })
        });
    </script>
```